# How to get Google voice input to "submit" / "enter"

Tags: keyboard, voice-command

Voice typing is convenient, having to press a keyboard button to submit or press enter is less so.

While 'native' apps like Google Assistant know when to submit according pauses or natural sentence structure, using Google voice typing in other contexts (even just the browser) doesn't automatically submit as far as I can tell.

*How does one, using their voice, perform the enter/go/done action for Google voice typing in lieu of the keyboard?*

Comment: I upgraded to Android 13 and it has `done` for Keep notes and `send` for SMS, but I havent found `enter` which would really expand the functionality to many more apps, even without official support like v13 has for specific actions like Chrome "new tab".